# Sample App seems too be overly complex

Tags: android, google-vision, android-vision

- [Android Vision Documentation](https://developers.google.com/vision/?hl=en)
- [Android Vision Sample Apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

I have been working with the Android Vision sample applications; however, I cannot seem to get them to detect anything.

I was trying to go through the code to see if I can make the simplest barcode scanner possible with Android-Vision, but it seems like the new API's don't actually support a few aspects.

It seems like all developers need to implement their own previews and overlays. All that is really simplified is the barcode recognition or the face detection software itself. Nothing with actually displaying it on the screen or the helpful overlays.

Is this correct? Again, I have been successfully ran the sample apps on my phone, but I have failed to actually be able to detect anything. I see no overlays, or anything, so it is hard to say what the APIs allow for and don't.

What is the simplest "Hello World"-like app that can be built to detect barcodes with a preview? Is the sample app the simplest?

Personally, I hope not, because it doesn't seem to improve the workflow of barcode scanning.

Comment: There is a new barcode reader sample app here:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

Comment: Thanks I will look at that. I became busy with other projects at the time, but I did notice my device space was low.....so I assume that was the problem. Haven't tested it, but I will mark your answer as right.

Comment: Will definitely check out the new sample. I will get back to Barcode detection in about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the API doesn't include a GUI component.  However, the sample apps have example GUIs for displaying the camera preview, tracking the barcode, and drawing overlay graphics.

I would guess that the reason that you aren't detecting anything with the sample app is that the vision libraries weren't successfully downloaded to your device.  This will happen if the device is in a "low storage" state.  We recently updated the samples to check for this condition and provide feedback to the user.  For example:

```
    // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
    // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
    IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
    boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

    if (hasLowStorage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
    }
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/photo-demo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/photo/PhotoViewerActivity.java#L91

This is something that we are working on improving.

Comment: I will try to test this soon. For the GUI component, are those basically the simplest solutions in the sample app?